# Use Windows git with Git Kraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

Just wondering if anyone has managed to point Git Kraken at their global git installation? I'd like to use global git config and so on with my installation but I can't seem to find where/how that's done?

It asks me for auth every time I perform an action and I'd like it to just read it from my config as other git clients do..

Comment: After 93M download (4 times, as it stalls) on win7, it won't install without login credentials, won't let me specify the login username, and EULA link is dead. Waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid what you want to achieve is not possible. As stated in the [GitKraken FAQ](https://www.gitkraken.com/faq) at "How can I open GitKraken from the CLI?
How can I open the command line from GitKraken?":

> Unlike other Git GUI clients, GitKraken is not a front-end GUI for your command line; no Git tools are required. It works directly with your repositories with no dependencies, which means a separate Git installation isn’t even required. Because of this, we currently do not offer direct integration between GitKraken and the CLI.

In reverse, this means that GitKraken only uses its own settings and has no way to access your global git installation.

Authentication via SSH keys can however be defined in GitKraken Prefenences -> Authentication.

edit: fixed typo

Comment: Ok... Thanks. So if you use a SSH key that will eliminate the need to log in every time I want to perform an action/session expires?

Comment: Yes, but this has to be set up server-side. When you use GitHub or GitLab, for example, you can add your SSH key to your account (described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) for GitHub) . When git knows abour your SSH key client side (i.e. you told GitKraken in Preferences->Authentication), you can perform actions on the respective repository without authentication.